# Binding element property from another xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Well, I have a style file that defines a custom dock panel for my MainWindow.

```
Title="Fancy App" Width="900" Height="730" Background="#37537F" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" >

<Window.Style>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="CustomWindowStyle"/>
</Window.Style>
```

The CustomWindowStyle.xaml defines some viewboxes for the controllers like minimize, maximize, etc. Something like that:

```
<Viewbox DockPanel.Dock="Right" Visibility="Visible">
<Border Width="74" Background="Transparent" MouseLeftButtonDown="MaximizeRestoreClick" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
    <Canvas Width="48" Height="48" >
        <Path Margin="10" Data="M4,4H20V20H4V4M6,8V18H18V8H6Z" Fill="White"/>
    </Canvas>
</Border>
```

So far so good.
What I want to achieve now is to access, let's say, the Visibility property of the Viewbox in the CustomWindowStyle from the MainWindow.xaml and change it.
I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give the `Viewbox` in your template an `x:Name`:

```
<Viewbox x:Name="viewBox">
...
```

...and override the `OnApplyTemplate()` method of your window class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        Viewbox vb = this.Template.FindName("viewBox", this) as Viewbox;
        if (vb != null)
            vb.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

You won't be able to access the `Viewbox` that you have defined in your `Style`/`ControlTemplate` from the XAML markup of the window.